# Frida Certificate Pinning is failing for all the apps

Tags: android, certificate, frida, pinning

I'm really new to android traffic intercepting. I just wanted to intercept a 3rd party app's API requests for some research. I started from official frida docs and reached up to the step unpinning the SSL certificate using [this guide](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/frida-certificate-pinning/).
I managed to successfully setup frida server on android device and it's running fine.
But whenever I try to bypass any app's certificate pinning I'm getting the same error below. I have tried many different apps having certificate pinning and all results the same error.
I'm using the following command for unpinning.

> frida -U -l ./frida-script.js -f tech.httptoolkit.pinning_demo

I'm using [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/httptoolkit/frida-android-unpinning/main/frida-script.js) to bypass certificate pinning and getting the following results.

```
Spawned `com.snapchat.android`. Use %resume to let the main thread start executing!
Error: getPackageInfoNoCheck(): has more than one overload, use .overload(<signature>) to choose from:
    .overload('android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo', 'android.content.res.CompatibilityInfo')
    .overload('android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo', 'android.content.res.CompatibilityInfo', 'boolean')
    at X (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:569)
    at K (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:564)
    at set (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-factory.js:932)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:224)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at _performPendingVmOpsWhenReady (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:244)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:204)
    at <anonymous> (/frida/repl-2.js:520)
    at apply (native)
    at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/core.js:51)
[Android Emulator 5554::tech.httptoolkit.pinning_demo]->
```

Using the %resume doesn't do anything and I still get error certificate rejected from the app server it's sending the requests to.

The error is same for even the demo app linked in the frida certificate unpinning guide.
Sorry if the explanation isn't enough and I'll be really thankful if someone is up to help.
Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a problem of the used code, instead it may be a bug in frida-java-bridge. You should create an issue frida-project on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% confirmed, but this appears to be a bug in Frida, either in the latest version of Frida (15.2.2) or Android (13).

See https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/2218 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct, this is a bug, probably on a13 devices. The trick is to run `%reload` in the frida shell after the error, this will cause the script to run and magically no error

https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/2218#issuecomment-1239983236